# Dashboard lights when ignition is turned on

Tags: battery

When I turn my ignition on the engine management light and red battery light stays on is this normal ? When I turn my engine on they both go off

Comment: +1 to cancel the -1 since even though this is a basic question it is not a bad question.  When you start your car and turn the key past the first click all the lights should turn on for a bit.  This lets you see any burned out bulbs.  Depending on you car they will then turn off at various points.  The engine one is only off when the engine is running properly, and not running is not running properly.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much all cars do some variant of that but you could check the owner's manual if you are concerned, if those lights have significance in your vehicle at that time it will be in the manual.

You can usually expect some dash lights to be on in normal conditions if the ignition switch is in the on position (as opposed to acc) but the engine isn't running.

Comment: You will also find that in a stalled state (i.e. engine stalled but ignition in run position) one or both of these lights come back one.  These are known as "Ignition Lights".